# Vue - Switching between components

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vuex

Imagine I have a order form with 3 stages - Personal details, Order details, payment.

I want to toggle the next component from within the previous one (hoping to adjust the value of 'step')

```
<Component1 v-if="step = 1"></Component1>
<Component2 v-else-if="step = 2"></Component2>
<Component3 v-else></Component3>
```

So, with those on my view, is it possible for me to pass the value of 'step' in to component1 and do something like

```
<button v-on:click="step = 2">
   Submit
</button>
```

then on that click, update the value of step on my main view (with the 3 components) and with that, hide my first completed component and displaying the second?

Thanks for any insight!

Comment: What exactly is your question? Did you try this and run into issues?

Comment: You need to bind the value into the component and then emit a new value to the parent when you click a link. If you emit the event `input` and bind the value `value`, then you can use `v-model`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why you dont use dynamic components?

On your parent component you listen to the event that changes yours step, i named it here `nextStep`. This event triggers the method `changeStep` that changes the component name.

```
<component @nextStep="changeStep" :name="selectedComponent"></component>

import component1 from "../components/component1.vue";
import component2 from "../components/component2.vue";
import component3 from "../components/component3.vue";
export default {
   data(){
      return {
         selectedComponent: "component1"
      }
   }
},
methods: {
   changeStep(step){
      this.selectedComponent = step;
   }
},
components: {
   component1,
   component2,
   component3
}
```

//in the child component

```
method: {
   changeStep(){
      this.$emit("nextStep", "component2");
   }
}
```

This is how you emit the event to the parent to change the component

You just need to change the property `selectedComponent` to the component name you want and it will change it

Comment: Could you extend your answer with how to two-way-bind the name (e.g. `v-model`)? I think he asked for that too.

Comment: @ssc-hrep3 you mean to emit the name to the parent?

Comment: Yes, exactly. 

Comment: Is it possible to move back to the last component on `history.back()`? Can I somehow add the component switch to the history?

Answer (score 0):

If you are still searching for the answer. This first code to add as your parent component.

```
 <template>
    <main>
        <component @nextStep="changeStep" v-bind:is="selectedComponent"></component>
    </main>
</template>
<script lang="ts">
import Setup1 from '@/components/Setup/Setup1.vue';
import Setup2 from '@/components/Setup/Setup2.vue';
import Setup3 from '@/components/Setup/Setup3.vue';

export default {
    name: "SetupView",
    components: {
        Setup1, Setup2, Setup3
    },
    data() {
        return {
            selectedComponent: "Setup1"
        }
    }, methods: {
        changeStep(step: string) {
            this.selectedComponent = step;
        }
    }, 
}

</script>
```

Add the code below as the child component .

```
<template>
        <div>
            Setup step 1
            <button @click="changeStep">Next step</button>
        </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
export default {
    name: "setup1", 
    methods: {
        changeStep() {
            this.$emit("nextStep", "Setup2");
        }
    }

}
</script>
```

v-bind:is="selectedComponent"

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).